# betweenness_centrality not implemented for multigrap type

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking

'''`import networkx as nx`

```
G=nx.MultiGraph()
import itertools
for inv in df[df["Top 5 Investors"].notnull()]["Top 5 Investors"].apply(lambda x : [val.strip() for val in  x.split(",")]):
   G.add_nodes_from(inv)
   for (a,b) in list(itertools.combinations(inv,2)):
         G.add_edge(a,b)
between_cent=nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
```

After this I got this error

NetworkXNotImplemented                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 between_cent=nx.betweenness_centrality(G)

in betweenness_centrality(G, k, normalized, weight, endpoints, seed)

1 frames
 in betweenness_centrality(G, k, normalized, weight, endpoints, seed)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py in _not_implemented_for(not_implement_for_func, *args, **kwargs)
74         if match:
75             msg = f"not implemented for {' '.join(graph_types)} type"
---> 76             raise nx.NetworkXNotImplemented(msg)
77         else:
78             return not_implement_for_func(*args, **kwargs)

NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for multigraph type

Comment: pls add a short summary of what you are trying to achieve with your code

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: I am trying to get betweeness_centrality for multigraph but it is showing me above error